# Why is the space between the 2 texts so big? Can I somehow make it smaller?

Tags: html, css

```html
<style>

      body {
        background: rgb(36, 36, 36);
        color: white;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        text-align: center;
      }

      @font-face {
        font-family: TypoRoundRegular;
        src: url(fonts/Typo_Round_Regular_Demo.otf);
      }

      * {
        font-family: "TypoRoundRegular";
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<h1 style="font-size:50px;"> Aetherian's Portfolio</h1>
<p style="line-height: 0;">Discord: Aetherian#6664</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Like said in the title, why is the space between the big header "Aetherian's Portfolio and "Discord: Aetherian#6664" so big?
https://gyazo.com/1c8b6c6271ebd9d5eab59ba637fb44de
I would like to get the bottom text much closer to the header text.

Comment: Both `h1` and `p` elements have vertical margins by default. Setting their margins to zero will tighten them up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your browser's developer tools to investigate what's going on.
You will see that `h1` has a certain `margin-bottom`.
To reduce it, add:

```
h1{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the default bounding box of the two elements.

[image: Bounding box example]

As you can see from the example (from firefox dev tools), there is the element itself, and the padding, border and margin.

If you reduce the `bottom-margin` of `h1` or reduce the `top-margin` of `p`, they will move closer together. These values can go into the negative if necessary.